# 500 Error after symfony update from 4.4.10 to 5.1

Tags: php, symfony

I made a symfony update from 4.4.10 to 5.1.

Therefore i called "composer update" more times with making changes like ..

1. Update TranslatorInterface to Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
2. Update errors.xml path to resource: '@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml' in twig.yaml
3. Commented config setting templating -> engines: ['twig', 'php']

Afterwards the "composer update" call is now working successfully without any errors.

But now i get a 500 error when i'm loading the page in my browser. And i don't get **any** error descriptions in Ubuntu 18.04 neither in var/log/dev.log nor in /var/log/apache2/error.log. And i can't find out until now why it isn't working.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: set `APP_ENV=dev` and `APP_DEBUG=1` in `.env.local` and try again

Comment: I made this change in .env.local (with clearing cache). But I still don't see an error message neither in var/log/dev.log nor in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Comment: Does something appear when running your PHPUnit tests ?

Comment: What do you get when you use the Symfony console?

Comment: symfony log and apache log are not your PHP log. check that.

Comment: I don't use any php unit tests at the moment

Comment: If i call ```php bin/console``` or ```php bin/console cache:clear``` in console everything is ok.

Comment: Ahhh ... in the php error log i got following error:

Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug' not found in public/index.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in public/index.php on line 24.

This helps me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now i know the problem. After update from from 4.4.20 to 5.1 you have also to update public/index.php because e.g. use path from Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug changed.

That's why I'm using this code in public/index.php now:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Taken from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.4/public/index.php

Thanks all for your help.